# Best way to make a black and white ggplot bar plot with multiple stacked sections in your bars?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to use ggplot to make bar graphs with stacked bars for a publication that only prints in black and white. I have 6 stacks for each bar, so using `scale_fill_grey()` makes it look weird and hard to read. Is there a better & cleaner looking way to do this?

Here's my data:

```
dput(head(Russets))
structure(list(Variety = structure(c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("Burbank 2018", 
"Norkotah 2018", "Silverton 2018", "Burbank 2019", "Norkotah 2019", 
"Silverton 2019"), class = "factor"), Rate = c("1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5", "1"), Hollow = c("67", "65", "64", "63", "67", "73"
), Double = c("42", "43", "42", "43", "48", "56"), Knob = c("351", 
"391", "362", "348", "357", "371"), AllCWT.AC = c("AVGCWT.AC.0.4", 
"AVGCWT.AC.0.4", "AVGCWT.AC.0.4", "AVGCWT.AC.0.4", "AVGCWT.AC.0.4", 
"AVGCWT.AC.0.4"), ValueCWT.AC = c(224.92342125, 226.91992125, 
226.967565, 237.4482825, 227.80791, 168.32446125), TuberSize = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0-4 oz", "4-6 oz", "6-10 oz", 
"10-13 oz", "13+ oz", "Culls"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

And here's my current ggplot:

```
RussetPlot <-ggplot(data=Russets,aes(x=Rate,y=ValueCWT.AC,group=interaction(TuberSize,Variety),fill=(TuberSize))) +
  geom_col(position = "stack",inherit.aes = TRUE) +
  facet_wrap(~Variety,nrow=2) +
  scale_color_discrete(name = "Tuber Sizes", labels = c("0-4 oz", "4-6 oz", "6-10 oz", "10-13 oz", "13+ oz", "Culls"))


print(RussetPlot)
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: When I run your code I only get a `TuberSize` for "0-4 oz" in the legend.I imagine this is due to the `dput(head(Russets))`. Have you looked into `scale_fill_manual(values = c())`?

Answer (score 4):

A more manual option (to build on @dc37's answer):

---

Using `scale_fill_manual()`

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = variable, y = number, fill = fact))+
    geom_col(color = "black)+
    theme_bw()+ 
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("grey10","grey30","grey50","grey70","grey80","grey90"))
```

[image]

---

**Data**

```
fact = rep(LETTERS[1:6],9)
number = rnorm(54)
variable = c(rep("a",18),rep("b",18),rep("c",18))
df = data.frame(fact,number, variable)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try `scale_fill_brewer` with the sequential palette `Greys`:

(As pointed out by @TheSciGuy, the example you provided does not recapitulate 6 different conditions, so it is not really helpful for trying codes on it).

I create a dummy example and here how it looks:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x = variable, y = number, fill = fact))+
  geom_col()+
  scale_fill_brewer(type = "seq", palette = "Greys")
```

[image]

With black and white theme of `ggplot2`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = variable, y = number, fill = fact))+
  geom_col(color = "black")+
  scale_fill_brewer(type = "seq", palette = "Greys")+
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

---

With the answer of @TheSciGuy, it reminds me you can use the `RColorBrewer` library to create your own palette:

```r
library(RColorBrewer)
col = colorRampPalette(c("white","grey","black"))(6)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = variable, y = number, fill = fact))+
  geom_col(color = "black")+
  scale_fill_manual(values = col) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

**Dummy data**

```r
fact = rep(LETTERS[1:6],9)
number = rnorm(54)
variable = c(rep("a",18),rep("b",18),rep("c",18))
df = data.frame(fact,number, variable)
```